# How to put UIWebView in a frame

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I would give `UIWebView` some particular size. For example, I would have a control widget beneath the `UIWebView`. I resized the `UIWebView` widget by using the IB, but when I run the app I get always a full-screen View, and the widgets I put below the `UIWebView` are superimposed to the widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should put it as a Subview:

```
[UIWebView *aWebView =[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,width,height)];
aWebView.delegate=self; 
[self.view addSubview:aWebView];
```

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically you should be able to add your `UIWebView` as a subview to a `UIView` like this:

```
UIView *containerView  = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,50,50,50)];

[containerView addSubview:yourWebview];
[self.view addSubView:containerView];
```

This snippet is not written in any form of IDE so it may or may not compile at all, it's also not tested but it looks credible.